# how to install gem manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that `client_side_validations` is not available as a `gem` for `Rails 4`. But there is a `4.0. beta` branch on github. When downloaded, how can I install it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify it in your bundle:

```
gem 'client_side_validations', 
    :git => 'git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git',
    :branch => '4-0-beta'
```

Comment: No problem, it's pretty handy especially with Rails 4 and gems slowly getting up to date.